# How do I custom sort a query on a subform?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query that has a "Status" field name with possible entries of "Overdue", "Due Soon", "In-Progress" and "Complete". I can display the records in that order when opening the query using `IIF`, but cannot translate it over to the subform that displays the query. I'd like the query to be sorted upon `Form_Open()`

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Me.frm_Stability.Form.OrderBy = "Status ASC IIf([Status]='Overdue',1,IIf([Status]='Due Soon',2,IIf([Status]='In-Progress',3,IIf([Status]='Complete',4))))"
Me.frm_Stability.Form.OrderByOn = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that if I applied my `IIF` statement to the subform's Sort & Filter, it would be accurately reflected on the main form. The underlying query seemed to be one degree too removed from the main form.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want your subform and your mainform sorted. The best way is you add a table in your Access database. Lets call this table **StatusSortOrder**. In this table you define your values, like that:

```
'Tablename: StatusSortOrder

----------------------------
ID    Status       SortOrder
----------------------------
1     Overdue      1
2     Due Soon     2
3     In-Progress  3
4     Complete     4
```

Dont use the ID as sord order. If you later have to change the sort order you can easily change the numbers in the column SortOrder, but you cant change the ID.
Now join your table with the table **StatusSortOrder** (Join Column is *Status*). Name the query f.e. **qryOutput**. In this query designer you can sort after column **SortOrder** ASC or DSC. If you use this query now as datasource in your main and sub form, it will be sorted the right way.